# chat.meta.stackoverflow.com shows error page

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

LOLcat arrives at my computer when I attempt to go to [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Cat free zone here. Try again.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Nope -- still happening.  Emptied cache, didn't help.

Comment: I understand the problem now, btw. Waiting on feedback internally.

Answer (score 2):

Logging out of meta and logging back in again seemed to clear up the problem.  Either that or a serendipitous fix.  Note:  I chose the "Logout Everywhere" option.  I also tried clearing my cache, which did not work.

Comment: you had a legacy cookie

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the log, there are a few recent "String or binary data would be truncated" errors. Different IP to yours, but maybe it is getting your proxy server or something.

I'll investigate, but I'm on the wrong machine at the moment.

Comment: Change your machines faster! (I cannot always write "fix that", can I?) FIX THAT, MARC! (Hey, I can! :)

Comment: meh; no chance. I'm on "family time". Food beckons.