# Can't see chat on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, chat

When I try to view the chat on Stack Overflow which shows on [this page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/). But when I'm logged out and try again now I can see my chat rooms. Why can't I see the chat room while I'm logged in?

Comment: [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com shows error page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60035) suggests clearing cookies should help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still now I can't see it.